# session timeout time - set by server?

Tags: php, session, zen-cart

I'm playing around with a zen-cart, and I'd like to have it so that a customers session doesn't expire after 24 mins, which appears to be the default.

After googling and hoking the zen-cart website it doesn't seem anyone has an answer to this (plenty of answers on how to change the Admin logout session time - I want people using the actual site to have longer sessions). I guess it's probably a security thing, none the less, I've looked into it now and can't figure out the code:

```
if (IS_ADMIN_FLAG === true) {
    if (!$SESS_LIFE = (SESSION_TIMEOUT_ADMIN > 900 ? 900 : SESSION_TIMEOUT_ADMIN)) {
      $SESS_LIFE = (SESSION_TIMEOUT_ADMIN > 900 ? 900 : SESSION_TIMEOUT_ADMIN);
    }
} else {
    if (!$SESS_LIFE = get_cfg_var('session.gc_maxlifetime')) {
      $SESS_LIFE = 1440;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the 1440 to 86400 (a day) but that didn't seem to work. I'm not completely sure what the line

```
if (!$SESS_LIFE = get_cfg_var('session.gc_maxlifetime')) {
```

does with that ! and only one = after. I guess this is the problem? Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Make sure you aren't sharing your session directory with other web sites. Otherwise, the site with shortest `gc_maxlifetime` will probably remove *all* session files, even yours.

Comment: @alvaro thanks, I think it's just easier to change the code for now :)

Comment: You've misunderstood me. Just changing the setting will be useless if you're on shared hosting and your session files are in a common directory. It's just a matter of checking `phpinfo()` and changing the `session.save_path` configuration directive if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$SESS_LIFE = get_cfg_var('session.gc_maxlifetime')) {
    $SESS_LIFE = 1440;
}
```

This gets the value of  **[`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)** from the runtime-configuration, and sets it as `$SESS_LIFE`.

**If the value of `$SESS_LIFE` is zero**, it executes `$SESS_LIFE = 1440;`

---

Change this timeout inside: `php.ini` or using

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
```

Or in your .htaccess, you can add the lines:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

**Reference: [`get_cfg_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php)**,

Comment: Ah ok, so could I just remove the if statement and set the variable $SESS_LIFE = 86400;  without using the ini_set? I'm not sure if I'm allowed to change things in ini_set on my live server, surely it could affect other sites then?

Comment: @crazysarah The `session.gc_maxlifetime` can be set inside a script or via `.htaccess`; there's really no need to change the code.

Comment: @crazysarah As Jack said, you could put it in your .htaccess as `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400`.

Comment: but changing the code is ok right? I'm more comfortable with that if there's no real bad downsides

Comment: @crazysarah It should be ok either way IMHO

Comment: Hopefully you understand the risks you're causing by allowing someone to come along several hours (a day, like you said) later and steal whatever information is sitting in the customer's session, such as personal address information and more. Great way to encourage identity theft for your customers. Just sayin...